# Undefined reference to jpeg_CreateDecompress() error when using libjpeg

Tags: c, linux, libjpeg

I install libjpeg-dev and all files are in the include folder

```
/usr/include/jerror.h
/usr/include/jmorecfg.h
/usr/include/jpegint.h
/usr/include/jpeglib.h
/usr/include/turbojpeg.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/jconfig.h
```

And when I try this simple code to decompress a jpeg image I got the error as in title.

here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
int main(void){
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
    jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The same problem has buged me for about two days!

my solution is use:

```
gcc your_code.c -ljpeg
```

instead of:

```
gcc -ljpeg your_code.c
```

to compile your code.

here is the explanation:[Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)

hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a linking error.

You are probably not linking to the library code; just including the header is *not* enough, that's not how C works.

Add something like `-ljpeg` last on your command line.

Comment: i used this version libjpeg-turbo8-dev